# Username and Password Validation in R Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a Shiny Login Page where user enters the username and password and hits login.

I have a  dataframe where set of login credentials where username and corresponding passwords are stored under the columns `username`, `password` respectively.

Below is my script in `server.r`

```
reactive({validate(
  need(input$Username == df$username, message = FALSE),
  need(input$Password == df$password, message = FALSE)
       )})
```

Now the issue is I am not able to validate the `username` with its corresponding `password`, any username with any password is able to login. Kindly help with the logic.

`df`

```
    username    password
       admin    admin
        jhon    jhon
        test    test
         ipt    ipt
        rock    rock
```

Comment: Storing password like that is very bad practice. Better to compare the hashed and salted password using the openssl package.

Comment: @JoshGilfillan Oh Okay, Thanks for the suggestion, but How do I implement that?

Comment: Use the sha512() function in the openssl package to store the hasshed password instead of the plain password. Then when a user enters credentials, compare the hash of the entered password with the hash of the stored password. The sha512() function also has a key parameter which prevents against dictionary attacks.

Comment: @JoshGilfillan , Thanks for the explanation. I ll surely try it our.

Comment: or you can use this https://www.shinyproxy.io/ but you need more than just R/shiny programming

Comment: Here's a great page that helped me when I started looking for ways to secure my applications with a login. 

http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2015/12/securely-storing-your-secrets-in-r-code.html

Answer (score 1):

You can require both username and password to match by concatenating them and comparing. The resulting string. I also have the passwords hashed here.

```
tbl <- read.table(text ="username    password
                         admin    admin
                         jhon    jhon
                         test    test
                         ipt    ipt
                         rock    rock", 
                  header= TRUE, 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(openssl)

tbl$password <- sha512(tbl$password)

auths <- apply(tbl, 1, paste, collapse = "_")

reactive({validate(
  need(paste0(input$Username,"_", sha512(input$Password)) == auths, message = FALSE)
)})
```

Comment: @Eumendies , thanks for the code. But the code doesnt seem to work. Now the validate function doesnt seem to be working. User is able to login though no `username` and `password` has not been entered.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Please can you provide the output of `paste0(input$Username,"_", sha512(input$Password))` when no username and password are provided?

Comment: It says `object input not found` .